# Creating waterfall graph using SSRS Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, graph, reportbuilder3.0, waterfall

I'm trying to create this Waterfall graph using SSRS Report Builder but still haven't figured it out:

[image: Waterfall graph]

Let's say I have this data :

In the start of 2013, I have a total of **125**

Now in 2013, each quarter has their own amount that eventually will sum up for the total amount in start of 2014 (which is **275**).

```
ID ||   Desc || Amount

1 ||    Q1 ||   80

2 ||    Q2 ||   -60

3 ||    Q3 ||   -40

4  ||   Q4 ||   175
```

Notice that the first and last bar are for the start of 2013 and the start of following year (2014). And also if the amount is negative, the bar will go down vice versa.

Can it be done with SSRS Report Builder?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this can be achieved in Report Builder alone.  I would try to create two series (one for the years, one for the quarters) and assign one series to the secondary axis.

The problem with just Report Builder is you need to set the Vertical Axis Min and Max for the Quarters series so that it appears as if the 0 value for Quarters = the 2013 value.  In your example the Min Value for the Quarters Vertical Axis should be -125, and the Max should be 150.

You might be able to come up with an SSRS Expression to derive those Min and Max values, but I doubt it.  I would try to pre-calculate those Min and Max values e.g. in SQL with a CTE.